# MVC2 - Are There Signals for Models?

Tags: django, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm just starting on my first ASP.NET MVC project (it's actually extending an existing MVC project that uses 4.0 and Linq2SQL). What I'm looking for is a way to create an instance of a model every time a different model is created (i.e., saved to the database). I see an `OnCreated()` method in the generated code, but that's in a partial class, so I can't replace it/ override it.

Is there a way to tie things together like this? I feel like I've been working in Django so long (where I would use a signal) that I don't know the right term to search for.

EDIT: What I want to do -- every time an instance of Model A is saved to the database for the first time (and only the first time), I want to create an instance of Model B and save that to the database.

And it looks like OnCreated() doesn't have anything to do with that.

Comment: Can you back up and explain what you're trying to do in more general terms?  Not sure what you mean by "create an instance of a model every time a different model is created."

Answer (score 0):

You can always override the save method.

```
class A(models.Model)

    def save(self,**kwargs):
        super(A,self).save(**kwargs)
        if self.pk:   #Primary Key is assigned only after the save.
            B.objects.create()
        return self
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I know how to do it in Django, but want to do something similar in Microsoft's MVC framework.